# asp:Chart - Moved to MVC5 - Less options?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, charts, asp.net-mvc-5

I am converting ASPX files to MVC, and have a few simple graphs that need converting.

Am I correct that the graphing capabilities in ASP, have more options that the ones in MVC when I add the System.Web.Helpers.Chart?

In ASP, they were using:

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" Width="600px" Palette="EarthTones">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, MVC does not have a direct equivalent built in. You will have to find an alternative solution. Most MVC developers will recognize that a chart is a client side UI concept, and therefore will locate a JavaScript based charting library. Asking for specific library recommendations is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Performing a web search for "JavaScript chart library" should set you down the right path.

This is due to the different approaches taken by the two frameworks: Web Forms attempts to do as much as possible on the server to mimic the development experience of Windows Forms. That leads to rapid application development, but doesn't always result in the best architecture. This isn't to say one is better than the other (you could use a JavaScript charting library in Web Forms too) but to emphasize the different approaches and each one has their pros and cons.

Comment: I thought I would be able to just convert them, and just noticed that the options weren't there. Appreciate your time